# ARCA Aerospace has announced the EcoRocket Heavy, a wider-than-tall rocket. Has there ever been any other seriously proposed rockets wider than tall?

Tags: history, launch-vehicle, conceptual

[image: Ecorocket Heavy]
Is this the first seriously proposed/planned launch vehicle that is wider than it is tall?
https://www.arcaspace.com/ecorocket

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://what-if-origin.sciesnet.net/24/).

Comment: I strongly question your use of "other" in the title.

Comment: It *does* work in KSP though.. :D

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom: I strongly question the use of "seriously" in the ultimate paragraph. To my knowledge, of all the "seriously proposed/planned launch vehicles" by ARCAspace, only *one* has ever launched … to an altitude of 1200m. Yes, that's meters, not miles. And ARCAspace has been around for longer than, say, SpaceX, Blue Origin, Rocket Lab, Astra, Firefly, Virgin Orbit, and Relativity, all of which have launched to space.

Answer (score 5):

The Chrysler Corporation's submission for the Shuttle program was pretty close (at least without the optional nose mounted payload).

[image]

Source: [Chrysler’s Radical Space Shuttle Design Was 50 Years Ahead of Its Time](https://www.thedrive.com/news/33905/chryslers-radical-space-shuttle-design-was-50-years-ahead-of-its-time)

Comment: As soon as I saw "Chrysler" I was hoping to see something like https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chrysler_Building_spire,_Manhattan,_by_Carol_Highsmith_(LOC_highsm.04444).jpg

Comment: @uhoh the linked article includes that wonderful Chrysler ad with the Saturn 1B and all their automobiles as well. Back when NASA went to the auto industry for engineering expertise.